# scikit-learn could not create one hot for a table

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset that has common categories for every column.

```
dataset = [['aaaa', 'bbbb'], ['bbbb', 'ffff'], ['aaaa', 'gggg']]
categories = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ffff', 'gggg']
```

I expect output must be:

```
output = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

code:

```
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ffff', 'gggg'])
return one_hot_encoder.fit_transform([['aaaa', 'bbbb'], ['bbbb', 'ffff'], ['aaaa', 'gggg']])
```

but show me this error:

> Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape
> (n_features,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output is not one-hot encoding; "one-hot" means one 1 ("hot") per row.  You may want to use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) instead.

To explain your error: sklearn thinks your input has two features (the two columns of the array), and if you provide `categories` to the encoder it must be a list of lists: *for each column*, the list of categories.